# URL masking on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, url-rewriting, routes, url-routing

Is URL masking possible with AWS?

Let me explain what is in-place and what I want.

I have a domain say example.com (ec2 instance which is not running) and under which I have a sub-domain called demo1.example.com (ec2 instance which is running) which have all my main website files. Now, I have a folder say "admin" inside demo1.example.com which holds my admin panel.

Now, I wanted to create another sub-domain demo2.example.com and redirect it to the admin folder "admin" under demo1.example.com which I did by writing a routing rule under s3 bucket and the redirection is also happening.

But, I want not to show my admin panel folder "admin" to the world i.e. when I should type demo2.example.com, the url shouldnot change and also it must point to demo1.example.com/admin

Thanks